# Salary after appraisal

Tags: salary

I have my 1 year appraisal coming up next month. I work as IT Support engineer, and before this job I worked as junior IT support engineer for 2 years. I am graduating with masters in Computer science in summer. As I joined the company and had my probation review after 3 months of joining it also included the pay rise which made my salary to £23000 per year. Now I know during my appraisal I will be asked about what salary I would like. Person who was doing my job before me as on £33000, however she didn’t do much and left everything in such a mess. Now my question is how much should I be asking for my pay? I am not very good at negotiating, however I don’t want to be left in the position where I am underpaid because I didn’t know how much I was worth. I hear good comments from management and they always praise my work.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I do believe it is important for them too because company were looking for someone who either had it or was in proccess of getting it.

Comment: Agreement when I started was that I get small pay rise after my probation (3months) and bigger pay rise once I competed 1 year and was close to finishing Masters.

Comment: You're going to be graduating and you're not interviewing for other jobs? It's difficult to know what you're worth if you don't.

Answer (score 3):

Do what anyone else would do when assessing their salary needs - look for vacancies for the same role in the same kind of industry in the same kind of geographical area and go from there.

If you've been given the salary of the person who left, then that's a great starting point (you at least know the budget for the head-count).

If you want more than that, you need to be able to justify why you deserve more (the previous person's lack of skill or motivation isn't counted as a reason).

Be prepared to be asked how you arrived at your desired salary level and why you deserve it.